# Where is Facebook's signed request going? google app engine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, facebook-authentication

I am really confused, because the documentation states that when a user registers from my website, using a facebook registration form, I am supposed to receive a signed request. I do not know where to look for it. Any replies would be appreciated. I am using Python in Google App Engine and I simply want to know where the signed request is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user sign-in on facebook is complete, your app will get POST request. Refer to some helpful blog posts [like this](http://blog.arunbalan.in/2011/09/20/facebook-canvas-apps-with-python-on-google-app-engine-super-simplified/) and [this](http://bitkickers.blogspot.sg/2011/12/migrate-your-python-app-to-facebook.html)

Comment: thank you I got it a little while back, but thank you for answering.